# Finite dimensionality of $V_1\times V_2\times \dots\times V_m$ implies $V_j$ is finite dimensional $\forall j$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, quotient-spaces

**Is my proof of the following proposition correct?**

**Proposition.** Given that $V_1,V_2,\dots,V_m$ are vector spaces such that $V_1\times V_2\times\cdots\times V_m$ is finite dimensional. Prove that $V_j$ is finite dimensional for each $j = 1,2,\dots,m$.

> *Proof.* Let $(u_{11},u_{12},\dots,u_{1m}),(u_{21},u_{22},\dots,u_{2m}),\dots,(u_{m1},u_{m2},\dots,u_{mm})$
>   be the basis of $V_1\times V_2\times\cdots\times V_m$. Now let
>   $j\in\{1,2,\dots,m\}$, we show that $V_j =
>  \operatorname{span}(u_{1j},u_{2j},\dots,u_{mj})$.
>
> Assume that $w\in V_{j}$, consequently $(0,0,\dots,w_j,\dots,0)\in
>  V_1\times V_2\times\cdots\times V_m$ and thus for some
>   $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_m\in\mathbf{F}$ we have 
>   $$(0,0,\dots,w_j,\dots,0)=\sum_{i=1}^{m}\lambda_i(u_{i1},u_{i2},\dots,u_{im})
> = \left(\sum_{i=1}^{m}\lambda_{i}u_{i1},\sum_{i=1}^{m}\lambda_{i}u_{i2},\dots,\sum_{i=1}^{m}\lambda_{i}u_{im}\right)$$
>   implying  $$w_j = \sum_{i=1}^{m}\lambda_{i}u_{ij}$$ and thus
>   $w_j\in\operatorname{span}(u_{1j},u_{2j},\dots,u_{mj})$ and by
>   extension
>   $V_j\subseteq\operatorname{span}(u_{1j},u_{2j},\dots,u_{mj})$, and
>   since $u_{1j},u_{2j},\dots,u_{mj}\in V_j$ it immediately follows that
>   $\operatorname{span}(u_{1j},u_{2j},\dots,u_{mj})\subseteq V$.
>
> $\blacksquare$

---

Comment: Yes, it is correct. There's just a subscript $j$ missing from the final $V$.

Comment: A better proof: $v_j \to (0,0,...,0,v_j,0...,0)$ is a one-to-one linear map from $V_j$ into the product, so $V_j$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: In the first line of your proof, you seem to assume that the dimension of $V_1\times V_m$ is $m$. Other than that, the proof seems correct. I like the idea of @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: One little remark : you give *a* (not *the*) basis of $V_1\times \cdots \times V_m$ that has $m$ vectors. Why would $V_1\times \cdots \times V_m$  be $m$-dimensional? It's better to use different letters for different variables.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1487489/prove-that-v-j-is-finite-dimensional-for-each-j-1-m

Comment: @ArnaudD. Thank you very much for pointing that out. Pardon my slopiness

Comment: I just realised you already asked to check a proof of this fact last year (essentially the proof given by Kavi Rama Murthy) : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2441799/implications-of-the-finite-dimensionality-of-v-1-times-v-2-times-cdot-cdot-cdot